# How to access sub class methods when sub class object is instantiated from abstact class

Tags: java, class, subclass, instantiation, abstract

I have an abstract class called A and class that extends from it called B. In the A class I have a concrete implementation of a method and also I have abstract methods. In class B I have overridden all abstract methods and a method of its own.

```
public abstract A{
   public boolean myConcreteMethod(){
      //implementation
   }

   public abstract void abstractMethod();
}

public class B extends A{
   @Override
   public void abstractMethod(){
       //implementation
   }

   public String aMethodBelongsToB(){
       //implementation
   }
}
```

Now when I instantiate an object of B like following:

```
 A test = new B();
```

I am unable to access

```
 test.aMethodBelongsToB();
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a normal fully documented behavior.

Comment: `A` does not have a method `aMethodBelongsToB`. Use `B test = new B();`?

Comment: And it has absolutely nothing to do with `A` being an `abstract` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate class `B`, you're using a reference variable to the type of `A`. From this reference, you can only access methods declared in `A`. That reference can also point to other classes that inherit from `A`, that would not have the methods declared in `B`, so the compiler doesn't let you call methods only declared in a subclass from a reference to a superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the B reference.so, you cannot call it's methods.You have to make it

```
B test = new B();
```

Now, B can access methods of A. Since B is A in OOP terminology. IS-A relationship!

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a `B` value to a variable of type `A`, the Java language says that it is not possible to call the `B`-specific methods.  Either do this:

```
    B test = new B();
    test.aMethodBelongsToB();
```

or this:

```
    A test = new B();
    ((B) test).aMethodBelongsToB();
```

Note: since we are casting `test` to `B` can now call the `B`-specific methods ... on the result of the typecast subexpression.

---

It is always the *declared type* of the variable/expression that determines what method (signatures) are available to be called.  The actual object reference only determines which actual method is called (if there is method overriding).  To understand why, consider this:

```
public class C extends A{
   @Override
   public void abstractMethod(){
       //implementation
   }
   ...
}
```

and this (which is not valid Java ...):

```
A test;
if (something) {
    test = new B();
} else {
    test = new C();
}
test.aMethodBelongsToB();  // INVALID
```

If that last statement was legal (and it isn't!!) what should happen there if `something` is false?